# Assessing covariate balancing with longitudinal data

Tags: r, panel-data, standardization, propensity-scores, time-varying-covariate

When assessing balance over covariates with cross-sectional data, one can use the standardized mean difference, i.e. the difference in mean for a given covariate among the treated and untreated groups divided by the mean of the standard errors.
$$
\frac{(\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_0)}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1+s^2_0}{2}}}
$$

But what about longitudinal treatments? In order to respect sequential randomization, should one use the mean conditional on past treatments? How would that be translated into a formula?

On a side-note, I could not figure what formula `cobalt`'s function `bal.tab.msm` in `R` uses to get the standardized mean difference with longitudinal treatments. I tried to replicate it, but could not find a way to get the same results.
**Edit**: the replication problem was due to an issue in my code, not in `cobalt`'s function, see the comments for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula `cobalt` uses is the same as that used for point treatments, i.e., the formula you gave. It treats each time period as a point treatment. There is no special way to calculate standardized mean differences for longitudinal treatments. Can you demonstrate how you are attempting to replicate the values `cobalt` produces?

There is a literature on assessing balance with longitudinal treatments that is ignored by `cobalt`. You can read more about that in [Jackson (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1097/EDE.0000000000000547). The R package [`confoundr`](https://github.com/jwjackson/confoundr) implements these methods.

Comment: I realize I was doing it wrong: instead of comparing the treated and untreated groups for each time period, I was computing the standardized mean difference for different treatment histories (never treated versus once treated, never treated versus twice treated...), which gives way worst results. I now can compute near-identical results to `bal.tab.msm` by scaling the data and computing the SMD for each year. The `confoundr` package seems interesting, but if standard SMD gives already robust results for time-varying treatments, I'll stay with `cobalt`.